# Are Holder Condition and signal to noise ratio (SNR) related?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, rough-paths

This question was posted in https://math.stackexchange.com but I got hardly any view. If posting here is an objection please let me know I would delete it immediately.

This question has evolved from watching the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dh5hHpJ79jc

In the video the speaker talked about white noise case and $\alpha$ related to the Holder condition, (wikipedia link to Holder condition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition)

The question: Is there a relation between SNR (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) and Holder condition?

Let me be more specific, As I understand, Rough path theory (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_path) is related to the solution of differential equation driven by non-smooth signals and non-smoothness is defined in terms of Holder condition. In the video it clearly relates the white noise case to the value of $\alpha$.   Consider our driver is simple sine wave, which is very smooth, but if we add a noise then we can define SNR of the driver based on the strength of the noise and at the same time can we define $\alpha$ based on the strength on the noise?

In some sense I am trying to define rough path theory in terms of SNR, is it possible? Any comments would be highly appreciated

Comment: Hölder exponent $h$, Hurst exponent $H$, and fractal dimension $D$ (with $D=2-H=1-h$) describe the _correlations_ in the fluctuations of the signal, not the strength of the fluctuations as quantified by the SNR.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thank you for your comments, but I did not understand how it is relates to the correlations. Mmay I request few more explanation or references which would help me to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hölder exponent $h$ and the Hurst exponent $H$ (related by $h=H-1$ for a continuous signal) characterise correlations in the noise, not the size of the noise (as quantified by the signal-to-noise ratio). So these are different quantities. This plot illustrates two signals with the same signal-to-noise ratio but different $H$ (short-term correlations on the left, long-term correlations on the right).

[image]
<sub>source: [On the relationship between the Hurst exponent, the ratio of the mean square successive difference to the variance, and the number of turning points](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02928)</sub>

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, I can understand  Hölder exponent  h (or alpha in the question) is greater then 0 for continuous signal, but I still could not get the relation h=H-1. In the paper, I did not get any mention about Hölder exponent  h. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: the relation between Hölder and Hurst exponents is discussed, for example, here https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0208028 (equation 2 and following text)

Comment: May I ask how do you know the plots have same signal to noise ratio?

Comment: just visual inspection: the curve $x(t)$ has variance close to unity in both plots.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Brownian_motion in the link the difference of H clearly shows that (visually) that SNR varies. May I please request your view?

Comment: can't you just rescale the data, subtract the time average and scale the vertical axis by an arbitrary factor; that will change the SNR but not H.

Comment: I am sorry, but in my opinion we cannot change SNR by re- scaling.

Comment: rescaling after subtraction of the average; you'll notice that in the two plots I showed in my answer the signal x(t) fluctuates around 0, so the average has been subtracted.